# how to pass a list of SQL Server tables into List Box in Excel and use it

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have made a report file in excel for analysts to check data every morning. How it looks like now:
[image]

Where button's script is the following:

```
  Sub Button6_Click()

    Dim qt As QueryTable

    sqlstring1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ReportUnits ORDER BY ProductID, CountryCodeID"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=getConnectionStr2, Destination:=Range("A3"), Sql:=sqlstring1)       

    End With

End Sub

Private Function getConnectionStr2()
'DRIVER={SQL Server};
getConnectionStr2 = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "DATABASE=em_CountryConsumer;" & _
                   "SERVER=555.555.55.15;" & _
                   "UID=User;" & _
                   "PWD=password;"
End Function
```

What I would like to do is to have additional List Box with the list of report tables in my SQL server database. In my example it is dbo.ReportUnits table, but there are much more report tables and they are creating automatically every day.

To give analysts a chance to choose table name. And then to show data by pressing Refresh button.

Is it possible?  Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Create a reference to the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects xxx library"
- Use the `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Recordset` objects to create a connection and define a query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
- Read column `TABLE_NAME` into the items of your (ActiveX) ListBox placed in the sheet or into a Listbox of a VBA form using `.MoveNext` and `EOF`

Comment: I am novice and have not so much experience..Can you please add more details? 
Thank you